# Invalid free(): boost::filesystem::path::~path()

Tags: c++, boost, free

I'm working on a program on a CentOS 7.5.1804 using the g++ 6.3.0 compiler

When I run the program, it returns a error:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./lost_drv 
*** Error in `./lost_drv': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002375cf8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81499)[0x7f5c65e85499]
./lost_drv(_ZN5boost10filesystem4pathD2Ev+0x18)[0x521564]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x9a)[0x7f5c65e3df4a]
/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.53.0(+0x7573)[0x7f5c68317573]
======= Memory map: ========
```

Valgrind reveals it to be an issue with the boost::filesystem::path destructor

```
-bash-4.2$ valgrind ./lost_drv 
==32523== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32523== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32523== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32523== Command: ./lost_drv
==32523== 
==32523== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==32523==    at 0x4C2B1CD: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==32523==    by 0x521563: boost::filesystem::path::~path() (path.hpp:55)
==32523==    by 0x73DBF49: __cxa_finalize (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==32523==    by 0x5053572: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.1.53.0)
==32523==    by 0x40101C9: _dl_fini (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==32523==    by 0x73DBBD8: __run_exit_handlers (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==32523==    by 0x73DBC26: exit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==32523==    by 0x73C444B: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
```

The error occurs after the final return statement, as everything is getting cleaned up.  The program apparently works OK prior to that.

This is an extensive program, but I've simplified it a bit by putting a return statement immediately following the main statement:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 return 0;
...
```

I am using boost::filesystem to check path integrity ... code like this:

```
try
    {
     boost::filesystem::path fn(ifilenm);
     if(!boost::filesystem::exists(fn) || !boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(fn))
        {
         cout << "ERROR: Input file does not exist or isn't a file:\t" << ifilenm << "\n";
         return -2;
        }
    }
 catch (const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& ex)
    {
     cout << "ERROR: Failed accessing input file.  File doesn't exist or isn't a file or isn't accesible:\t" << ifilenm << "\n";
     return -3;
    }
```

Which isn't being run in this degenerate case of course.  There aren't any global boost variables being initialized before execution either.

I've tried this with the system boost install (1.53) as well as static & dynamic links against boost 1.59 built with the g++ 6.3 compiler.  Same behavior.

One more bit ... there's another version of this executable which accesses some additional functionality via linking against some other 3rd party libraries.  That build doesn't have this problem.

One other data point - if I rebuild the whole business with the default CentOS 7 compiler (g++ 4.8.5), I don't get this error.  But that's not an option overall, because the 3rd party libraries used for the full monty require g++ 6

Any idea what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: What's going on here is a valuable lesson in C++: just because the program crashes somewhere, in this case, inside `boost::filesystem`, doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in your code. Pretty much anywhere in your code a bug can end up dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, just as an example, or overwriting a buffer and crapping all over what by chance happens to be some boost object. And when you get around to running boost code: crash! A bug in boost is always possible, but it's likely a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: Sure, been there done that.  But in this case, the program is doing literally nothing other then allocating a few globals and exiting.  Must be in one of the constructors for the one of the classes used by a global.  That'll be fun to track down.

Comment: One idea you might want to look into is to check whether you're using the same compiler with the *same C++ ABI* settings to build both Boost and your application. The `path` destructor calls `std::string` destructor, and `std::string` has different ABI in libstdc++ from gcc 4.8 and 6 in the C++11/14 mode.

Comment: I've taken a closer look at the globals.  It's all native types (bool, int, double, etc.) a few strings, and stl vectors of objects or pointers to objects.  There is one constructor for one of our classes called - but I've gone in and edited the constructor to return immediately.  And still getting this crash.  I'm at a loss on how to proceed here.

Comment: @CoAstroGeek I'm facing the same problem, it cost me too much time. How did u workaround about this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @wind2412, as far as I can tell this is due to some mismatch in the compiler used to build boost and the compiler used to build the program - what Andrey said above.  I've changed my build system to use Environment Modules (http://modules.sourceforge.net/) and built boost  (and other dependencies) and my code with the same compiler, and the problem went away.

Comment: @CoAstroGeek Thank you! It's the compiler's problem.;)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem when compiled on CentOS 7 with gcc 9.2.0. Worked fine on Amazon Linux 2. Substituted boost::filesystem::copy_file with std::filesystem::copy but required compiling with C++17.

Changed this:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::copy_file
    (
        "./testFilesystemCopy.cpp",
        "./testFilesystemCopy.cpp-copy"
    );
  
    return 0;
}
```

To this:

```
// testStdFilesystemCopy.cpp
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{ 
    std::filesystem::copy
    ( 
        "./testStdFilesystemCopy.cpp",
        "./testStdFilesystemCopy.cpp-copy"
    );
  
    return 0;
}
```